# Jquery can't close div on click again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slidetoggle, slideup

I am trying to close a div by clicking a button with SlideUp function.
But when I click on button it opens as expected and closes other divs. But doesn't close it re-opens itself.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="row all-row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="main-acc">
                <div class="brand-wrapper">
                    <img src="img.png" alt="">
                    <h5 class="p-3">Lorem</h5>
                    <div class="card-wrapper">
                        <div class="card border-0 text-center">
                            <h5>Ipsunlore</h5>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius unde est ut consequatur error amet eligendi vero aut assumenda.
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="">Find</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="btn d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center opener" href="#">
                        <h5 class="m-0">Lorem</h5> 
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pl-3"></i>
                    </a>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="main-acc">
                <div class="brand-wrapper">
                    <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
                    <h5 class="p-3">Lorem</h5>
                    <div class="card-wrapper">
                        <div class="card border-0 text-center">
                            <h5>Mister: Ipsun</h5>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius unde est ut consequatur error amet eligendi vero aut assumenda.
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="">From</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="btn d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center opener" href="#">
                        <h5 class="m-0">Lorem</h5> 
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pl-3"></i>
                    </a>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is the Jquery codes:

```
<script>
    $(".opener").click(function(){
    $(".all-row").find(".card-wrapper").slideUp();
    $(this).closest(".card-wrapper").slideToggle(); 
    
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Might it make sense for you to use an accordion for this? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/ I'm struggling to understand the behavior you want vs. the behavior you're seeing. Maybe you could try to explain that more clearly.

Comment: it makes sense of course but i am trying to learn jquery.

Comment: every time `.opener` is clicked every `.card-wrapper` within `.all-row` will close, whether or not it is open, therefore clicking `.opener` will alway also close the `closest` `.card-wrapper`, even if it is already closed, and then toggle it open. I suggest using a state class,  like `is-open`.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), which finds the closest matching parent. But what you need is [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) because the element you want to target is the previous sibling... Not it's parent.

Additionnaly, you should remove this targeted element form the "all" `.card-wrapper` collection, using [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```js
$(".opener").click(function() {

  // The card previous to the clicked .card-opener anchor
  var this_card = $(this).prev(".card-wrapper")

  // Make sure all cards closes EXCEPT this one
  $(".all-row").find(".card-wrapper").not(this_card).slideUp();
  
  // Toggle this one
  this_card.slideToggle();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row all-row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="main-acc">
      <div class="brand-wrapper">
        <img src="img.png" alt="">
        <h5 class="p-3">Lorem</h5>
        <div class="card-wrapper">
          <div class="card border-0 text-center">
            <h5>Ipsunlore</h5>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius unde est ut consequatur error amet eligendi vero aut assumenda.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="">Find</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center opener" href="#">
          <h5 class="m-0">Lorem</h5>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pl-3"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="main-acc">
      <div class="brand-wrapper">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
        <h5 class="p-3">Lorem</h5>
        <div class="card-wrapper">
          <div class="card border-0 text-center">
            <h5>Mister: Ipsun</h5>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius unde est ut consequatur error amet eligendi vero aut assumenda.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="">From</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center opener" href="#">
          <h5 class="m-0">Lorem</h5>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pl-3"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now.

Comment: My pleasure. A trick: Use the `console.log()` function to degug. You would have noticed there was no parent with class `card-wrapper` by console logging `$(this).closest(".card-wrapper").length`. ;)